# how to add sweet alert confirm in jquery

Tags: jquery

Good evening,
I am a beginner in developing JS, I tried several times to make a confiramation (sweet alert) to the user when trying to delete an item.

> I use any event to trigger the alarm?

this my code in Html:

```
     <!-- sweet alerts Css-->
          <link href="{{ asset('template/assets/sweet-alert/sweet-alert.min.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- sweet alert JS-->
        <script src="{{ asset('template/assets/sweet-alert/sweet-alert.min.js') }}"></script>
        <script src="{{ asset('template/assets/sweet-alert/sweet-alert.init.js') }}"></script>

<!-- form--->
     <form id="deleteAll" method="post" action="{{ path('projets_deleteAll') }}" 
    <!--checkAll --->
     <input type="checkbox" id="checkAll"/>

     {% for entity in entities %}
        <input type="checkbox" id="d" name="check[]" value="{{ entity.id}}"/>
    {% endfor %}

     <strong >
     <button type="submit" class="btn btn-lg btn-danger" id="bn"  >
           <i class="fa fa-trash" ></i> Delete</button>
     </strong>
    </form> 
<!-- ./form--->
```

-Code Jquery.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

        $("#checkAll").click(function(){

            var checked_status = this.checked;

            $("input[name='check[]']").each(function(){

                this.checked = checked_status;
                var v = $("#d").val();

                $('#bn').trigger('submit', function (e){
                    e.preventDefault();
                    actiondesubsitution();
                });

        });
    });

        if(v.length>0){

            document.querySelector('#d').onclick = function(){
                swal({
                            title: "Are you sure?",
                            text: "You will not be able to recover this imaginary file!",
                            type: "warning",
                            showCancelButton: true,
                            confirmButtonColor: '#DD6B55',
                            confirmButtonText: 'Yes, delete it!',
                            closeOnConfirm: false
                        },
                        function(){
                            swal("Deleted!", "Your imaginary file has been deleted!", "success");
                        });
            };
        }
        else{
            new SweetAlertDialog(this, SweetAlertDialog.ERROR_TYPE)
                    .setTitleText("Oops...")
                    .setContentText("No selection for deleting !")
                    .show();
        }
    });
```

> the problem that the alert is not functional at "if"

the error is:

> VM1631:187 Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'querySelector' on
>   'Document': '[object HTMLDocument]' is not a valid selector.
>       at Error (native)
>       at CommandLineAPIImpl.$ (<anonymous>:187:84)
>       at <anonymous>:1:1CommandLineAPIImpl.$ @ VM1631:187(anonymous function) @ VM1633:1 javascript:
>   console.log(v.length); VM1634:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: v is not
>   defined
>       at <anonymous>:1:25(anonymous function) @ VM1634:1

Thank you for helping me to integrate this alert.

Comment: You are adding tons of event handlers to deleteAll...

Comment: *Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a [mcve].* I'm not suggesting you put an entire 3rd party library in your question but you do need to include enough of your code to duplicate the issue.

Comment: my question is clear, looking for how to include the sweet alert code in jQuery code my nickname because I have not developed before JS. any event I can use ? this my problem.

Comment: `if(v.length>0){...` this doesn't work because it gets executed once when the page is loaded and `document.querySelector('#d').onclick` never gets added... you can solve it by putting the if condition inside `document.querySelector('#d').onclick = function(){`.

Comment: I tried but still not functional. I did a test and I put the error in the topic to the top

Answer (score 1):

I assume you include `<script src="dist/sweetalert.min.js"></script>` and `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="dist/sweetalert.css">` tags, if you did, all you have to do is put the second code inside the function linked to the event, like you can see if you press F12 on the demo page and check the code on the script tag at the end:

```
document.querySelector('ul.examples li.warning.confirm button').onclick = function(){
   swal({
      title: "Are you sure?",
      text: "You will not be able to recover this imaginary file!",
      type: "warning",
      showCancelButton: true,
      confirmButtonColor: '#DD6B55',
      confirmButtonText: 'Yes, delete it!',
      closeOnConfirm: false
   },
   function(){
      swal("Deleted!", "Your imaginary file has been deleted!", "success");
   });
};
```

try:

```
$(document).on("click", "#bn", function(){
   swal({
      title: "Are you sure?",
      text: "You will not be able to recover this imaginary file!",
      type: "warning",
      showCancelButton: true,
      confirmButtonColor: '#DD6B55',
      confirmButtonText: 'Yes, delete it!',
      closeOnConfirm: false
   },
   function(){
      swal("Deleted!", "Your imaginary file has been deleted!", "success");
   });
});
```

I can't test it but this will show your message... but I'm not sure how it will link the deleting elements function...

The code should look like this:

```
$(document).on("click", "#bn", function(){
  if(v.length>0){
    swal({
      title: "Are you sure?",
      text: "You will not be able to recover this imaginary file!",
      type: "warning",
      showCancelButton: true,
      confirmButtonColor: '#DD6B55',
      confirmButtonText: 'Yes, delete it!',
      closeOnConfirm: false
    },
    function(){
      swal("Deleted!", "Your imaginary file has been deleted!", "success");
    });
   }
   else{
        new SweetAlertDialog(this, SweetAlertDialog.ERROR_TYPE)
                .setTitleText("Oops...")
                .setContentText("No selection for deleting !")
                .show();
    }
});
```

Does it?

The condition should be evaluated inside the event, because at that point is when your `v` should have values...

Comment: thank you for this code, I tried to change my code but still alert 'is functional thank you for helping me to correct the problem :)

Comment: @Cros Well I came to learn that helping others with their issues I learn a lot, so no problem and happy coding.

Comment: until now I have not found the solution. thank you for helping me

Comment: Sometimes it's better to create your own solution than try to accommodate some great plugin that just won't work... specially project time wise. But then again, the `document.querySelector('ul.examples li.warning.confirm button').onclick` should be your delete button onclick... I believe is: `<button type="submit" class="btn btn-lg btn-danger" id="bn"  ><i class="fa fa-trash" ></i> Delete</button>` so `$("#bn").click(function(){ swal({...} });` should work.

Comment: if I add your proposal still alert does not start and the button is not functional CheckAll :(

Comment: @Cros What errors are being show in the [console](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/debug/console/console-ui?hl=en)?